# Fill a block of parent template from included child template

Tags: python, jinja2

I am just starting out with jinja2 template library. I can't figure out how to fill content in a block of parent template from included child template.
For example I have a parent template-

t-1:

```
<div id="includedTemplateName>
    {% block includedTemplateName %}{% endblock %}
</div>

<div id="content">
    {% include 't-2.htm' %}
</div>
```

and child template

t-2:

```
<div>
conten
</div>
{% block includedTemplateName %}t-2{% endblock %}
```

I want value in div with id `includedTemplateName` to be 't-2' as defined in t-2.
How can I achieve this with jinja2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the `include` statement with template inheritance. *The include statement is useful to include a template and return the rendered contents of that file into the current namespace* (from [Jinja2 docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include)). Your "child" template is already rendered when it's included, so there isn't any way for it to change values in your parent.

You need to use [template inheritance](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#template-inheritance).

`t1.html`:

```
<div id="includedTemplateName">
    {% block includedTemplateName %}{% endblock %}
</div>

<div id="content">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

`t2.html`:

```
{% extends "t1.html" %}
{% block includedTemplateName %}t-2{% endblock %}
{% block content %}content{% endblock %}
```

From [the Jinja2 docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#child-template):

> The `{% extends %}` tag is the key here. It tells the template
>   engine that this template “extends” another template. When the
>   template system evaluates this template, first it locates the parent.
>   The extends tag should be the first tag in the template. Everything
>   before it is printed out normally and may cause confusion.